# Google AppScript -> DocumentApp -> Extract list item index

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Does anybody know how to extract the ListItem index as a formatted string?

p.asListItem().getText() give back the string  "Legend" but I need instead "1.1."

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### At current stage this is not possible

There is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/36762456) for this on Google's Public Issue Tracker.

Give it a "star" to increase visibility - the more people show their interest in the feature, the more likely it is that the feature will be implemented in future.

Comment: Thanks, I found a work around in meantime, but this will be useful if they ever fix it.